# Как выделить и удалить по атрибуту в файле json

Tags: json

Используется json файл для автоответа и форворда с почты уволенного работника на почту другого сотрудника, а отправителю автоответ с текстом "Больше на работает бла, бла....") Строка "Start_Date" пока вообще ничего не делает, только визуальная информация для того, чтобы через какое-то время просмотреть и удалить полностью этого человека из json, ну примерно через 6 месяцев. Хотелось бы автоматизировать это, чтобы автоматически у тех у кого прошло пол года от Start_Date они удалялись с файла. Не знаю возможно можно написать скрипт Powershell.

[image: Сам json файл]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте кусок `json`-а текстом, а не картинкой. Так на каком языке вам надо решение, или всё-равно? Проще всего на питоне, наверное, будет.

Comment: Желательно чтобы это был Powershell или json.

Часть кода:

{

"Dismiss" :{
   "MailBoxs":
[
   {
"MailBox": "autoreply@test.com",
"From_Where_Folder: "Inbox",
"Where_Folder": "ARR",
"Sent_Items_Folder": "ARSI",
"Not_Answered_Folder": "ARNR",
"Aliases":
 [
   {
      "Alias" : "Name.Surname@test.com:,
      "Start_date" : "2021-10-30",
      "Autroreplu_Massage" : "This person quit.."
      "Forward_Mailbox" : "info@test.com",
    "Forward_Subject" : "Name.Surname@test.com"
},